# Optimize code structure for `pathos.multiprocessing`

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, pathos

I have the following code structure:

My `Base` class is defined in the first module. It contains a number of attributes, properties and methods. Some of the latter use the former two to calculate additional results which are also stored as cached properties, because this calculations can be quite CPU expensive.

```py
# in base.py

from optional import Optional

class Base:
    
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b        
        ##### more attributes...
    
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_prop1'):
            self._prop1 = self.calc_prop1()
        return self._prop1
    
    ##### more properties like this...
    
    def calc_prop1(self):
        # expensive calculation that uses self.a, self.b etc...
        return prop1
    
    
    def add_optional(self):
        self.optional = Optional(self)
    
    
    def expensive_function(self,x,y):
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        
        d = self.optional.d
        
        # CPU expensive code
        
        return results
```

Instances of `Base` can also contain an instance of `Optional` which is defined in a second module:

```py
# in optional.py

import base        
        
class Optional:

    def __init__(self, base : 'base.Base'):
        self.a = base.a
        self.prop1 = base.prop1
    
    def calc_d(self):
        # expensive calculation that uses self.a, self.b, self.prop1 etc...
        self.d = result
```

The instance of `Optional` uses many of the data contained in the `Base` instance (attributes and properties) to do its own expensive calculations that deliver results which also have a large data footprint.

**Eventually, this means that instances of `Base` are relatively large, especially when they contain an `Optional` object.**

Now I want to employ `pathos.multiprocessing` for e.g. `Base.expensive_function` when iterating over many `x` and `y`. Although `pathos` uses `dill` and is thus capable of serializing the method, this will require the whole `Base` instance to be sent to all workers for each process (*right?*). The resulting overhead kills all potential benefits of the multiprocessing.

My current workaround is to define a `Reduced_Base` class and move `expensive_function` there, like this:

```py
class Reduced_Base:
    def __init__(self,base : Base):
        self.a = base.a
        self.d = base.optional.d
    
    def expensive_function(self,x,y):
        a = self.a
        
        d = self.d
        
        # CPU expensive code
        
        return results
```

I can then use `Reduced_Base.expensive_function` for my parallelization instead of `Base.expensive_function`. This way, the object sent to the workers (an instance of `Reduced_Base`) only contains the necessary data from `Base` and `Optional` for `expensive_function`.

**Is there a better solution?** I first tried to to contain the data for `expensive_function` in a closure but `multiprocessing` doesn't seem to work with dynamically created function objects.

Apart from that: Are there additional measures that could increase the performance when using multiprocessing?

Comment: maybe make `CPU expensive code` use multiprocessing directly?

Comment: I do not understand why you need to serialize any method. Are they generated on the fly and passed as a value?

Comment: @dankal444: you mean by methods outside of Python like mpi? The expensive part is basically a loop where each iteration takes a couple of seconds.

Each of these iterations runs a method/function that requires some of the data contained in the `Base` object and the function arguments.

Comment: why you need pathos and dill? why you need to pass functions as data?

Comment: I have to pass some data to each iteration's function call. That data comes from my `Base` instance. So I either pass the instance itself, some reduced version of it, or I wrap it in a closure. As far as I know, this requires dill. Not true?

Comment: But why the data must consists of functions too? If you get rid of passing functions as data, you could use multiprocessing and have faster serializing. The best solution to solve a problem is not creating it in the first place