# Analyze what exactly is being serialized when using pathos multiprocessing

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing, profiling, pathos

I have a class object that uses `pathos.multiprocessing` to parallelize one of its more CPU expansive methods. To reduce overhead, I actually moved the method outside of the original class into a reduced class with a smaller data footprint (Whether this is a good design is another question which I posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77055903/optimize-code-structure-for-pathos-multiprocessing)).

I tested this first on a Windows system and obtained some performance improvements, although I still assume serialization overhead to be a limiting factor.

**However, when I tried the same on a Unix system, the parallelized version runs significantly slower than the sequential one.** This surprises me, because although my understanding is limited, I was under the impression that efficient multiprocessing in Python is easier to achieve on a Unix system due to its ability to fork processes.

I would like to investigate what exactly causes this difference in performance for the two systems, but debugging multiprocessing programs has always struck me as a complicated task: **To begin with, is there a way to obtain information on what exactly is passed (i.e. serialized and sent) to each subprocess during the execution of `ProcessingPool.imap`?** This information could help me in further improving the design of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `dill`, `multiprocess`, and `pathos`.  The easiest thing to do is to use `dill.detect.trace` which provides a trace of the path used to serialize any object.

For example:

```
Python 3.8.18 (default, Aug 25 2023, 04:23:37) 
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def bar(self):
...     pass
... 
>>> dill.dumps(Foo)
┬ T2: <class '__main__.Foo'>
├┬ F2: <function _create_type at 0x10fc648b0>
│└ # F2 [30 B]
├┬ T1: <class 'type'>
│├┬ F2: <function _load_type at 0x10fc64820>
││└ # F2 [17 B]
│└ # T1 [28 B]
├┬ T1: <class 'object'>
│└ # T1 [15 B]
├┬ D2: <dict object at 0x010f8cb740>
│├┬ F1: <function Foo.bar at 0x10fe16ee0>
││├┬ F2: <function _create_function at 0x10fc64940>
│││└ # F2 [23 B]
││├┬ Co: <code object bar at 0x10fe1b450, file "<stdin>", line 2>
│││├┬ F2: <function _create_code at 0x10fc649d0>
││││└ # F2 [19 B]
│││└ # Co [77 B]
││├┬ D1: <dict object at 0x010f1fdec0>
│││└ # D1 [22 B]
││├┬ D2: <dict object at 0x010fe15d80>
│││└ # D2 [2 B]
││├┬ D2: <dict object at 0x010fe15c80>
│││├┬ D2: <dict object at 0x010fe15d40>
││││└ # D2 [2 B]
│││└ # D2 [49 B]
││└ # F1 [185 B]
│└ # D2 [230 B]
└ # T2 [349 B]
b'\x80\x04\x95^\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\ndill._dill\x94\x8c\x0c_create_type\x94\x93\x94(h\x00\x8c\n_load_type\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x04type\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x8c\x03Foo\x94h\x04\x8c\x06object\x94\x85\x94R\x94\x85\x94}\x94(\x8c\n__module__\x94\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x03bar\x94h\x00\x8c\x10_create_function\x94\x93\x94(h\x00\x8c\x0c_create_code\x94\x93\x94(K\x01K\x00K\x00K\x01K\x01KCC\x04d\x00S\x00\x94N\x85\x94)\x8c\x04self\x94\x85\x94\x8c\x07<stdin>\x94h\x10K\x02C\x02\x00\x01\x94))t\x94R\x94c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x10NNt\x94R\x94}\x94}\x94(\x8c\x0f__annotations__\x94}\x94\x8c\x0c__qualname__\x94\x8c\x07Foo.bar\x94u\x86\x94b\x8c\x07__doc__\x94Nut\x94R\x94\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x07setattr\x94\x93\x94h(h#h\x08\x87\x94R0.'
```

The `#` denotes an object is completed, and an indentation is that a group of other objects are needed to serialize the current object.  Thus, the serialization path is traced out.

This also works for multiprocessing...

```
>>> import pathos
>>> pathos.multiprocessing.Pool().map(lambda x:x*x, [1,2,3])
F2: <function mapstar at 0x10fe7bca0>
# F2
F1: <function <lambda> at 0x1100ad670>
F2: <function _create_function at 0x10fc64940>
# F2
Co: <code object <lambda> at 0x1100979d0, file "<stdin>", line 1>
F2: <function _create_code at 0x10fc649d0>
# F2
# Co
D3: <dict object at 0x010f1fdec0>
# D3
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0b40>
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0780>
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0a80>
# D2
# D2
# F1
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0340>
# D2
F2: <function mapstar at 0x10fe7bca0>
# F2
F1: <function <lambda> at 0x1100ad670>
F2: <function _create_function at 0x10fc64940>
# F2
Co: <code object <lambda> at 0x1100979d0, file "<stdin>", line 1>
F2: <function _create_code at 0x10fc649d0>
# F2
# Co
D3: <dict object at 0x010f1fdec0>
# D3
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0b40>
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0880>
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0a80>
# D2
# D2
# F1
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b06c0>
# D2
F2: <function mapstar at 0x10fe7bca0>
# F2
F1: <function <lambda> at 0x1100ad670>
F2: <function _create_function at 0x10fc64940>
# F2
Co: <code object <lambda> at 0x1100979d0, file "<stdin>", line 1>
F2: <function _create_code at 0x10fc649d0>
# F2
# Co
D3: <dict object at 0x010f1fdec0>
# D3
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0b40>
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b09c0>
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0a80>
# D2
# D2
# F1
D2: <dict object at 0x01100b0340>
# D2
[1, 4, 9]
>>>
```